# Android list - hiding items in the backing array

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-recyclerview

I guess I sort of *know* the answer (that it cannot be done), but still I'd love to hear from the SO community if anyone has come across something like this:

I have an ArrayList of items that I want displayed in a list/recycler view. So I have an adapter reading off of this backing array. Now I'd like to hide some of the items based on certain properties of the items in the array. How do I setup the adapter to *skip* some of the items in this array?

I tried having a reference to the parent view from the holder, and setting its visibility. This makes the view invisible, but the list still shows empty rows.

Comment: Set it to GONE instead of INVISIBLE

Comment: Couldn't you just create a separate array to store the filtered results, and then just read out of that array? Why do you need to use a property of the array items to tell the adapter to skip those items? It seems like that would just be unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @BenTrengrove, that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @TrevorHart Yes that was my backup plan, but since my array changes in the background, for every change I'd have to create a new list. I was trying to avoid so much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this, You need to override getItemViewType in adapter

Your Pojo

```
Hello.java
{
  boolean needHide =false;
}
```

Adapter:

```
int ITEM_TYPE_USER_HIDE =0;
int ITEM_TYPE_USER_UNHIDE=1;

 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mList.get(position).needHide? ITEM_TYPE_USER_HIDE : ITEM_TYPE_UNHIDE;
    }
 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_UNHIDE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_not_hide, parent, false);
            return new NotHideHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_hide_type, parent, false);
            return new HideViewHolder(view);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting solution and it worked for my need. The layout file I used was like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"      
     android:layout_height="0dp" />`

Comment: Just proves the adage- _anything is possible as long as it is software!_

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as @Ben Trengrove recommended, setting visibility to View.GONE is not working with ListView as it still holds space in the list as an empty row.

But I was working on a project and faced similar problem, and Fortunately I finally find a solution for it.
I use a ListView and an ArrayAdapter. My strategy is that whenever we want to hide a view we will return a view without inflating it from the getView() method of the ArrayAdapter.
Here is the complete working code of my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;
private Typeface typeface;
private ArrayList<String> list;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.simple_list_view_1, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    typeface  = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "krdv010.ttf");
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
/*Every time ListView needs to show a new row on screen, it will call
 this getView() method.*/
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    //Hide some views here...
    //Use position or whatever for the condition.
    //Provide a new View and return it without inflating it.
    //but still set a ViewHolder tag to it.
    if (position ==0 || position == 6 || position ==26){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.isEmpty = true;
        convertView = new View(context);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    //ListView is not asking you to recycle a view - normal workout
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_view_1, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        viewHolder.isEmpty = false;
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    //Here ListView is asking you to recycle the row layout.
    //But there may be the one which was not inflated.
    //So we will check for it and do what is required.
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        if(viewHolder.isEmpty){
            //This is the one which wasn't inflated.
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_view_1, null);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            viewHolder.isEmpty = false;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
    }




    //Your normal business here
    String string = list.get(position);

    viewHolder.textView.setText(string);
    viewHolder.textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

//The View Holder Class
private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    Boolean isEmpty;
}
}
```

and here is the screen shot, notice there is no empty row @0 and @6 position they are hidden successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This still created empty rows in the layout. @Ajay's proposal worked for.

Comment: oh! but its working for me just tested this morning, please share ur code, let me look at it...

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and I am marking it useful). I am sure it works for listview. I am on recycler and not creating/setting a view does not seem to work.

Comment: @GreenBee Thanks dev